# Toggling between bold and normal text with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently working my way through Learning jQuery 4th Edition by Packtpub, trying out one of it's exercises on DOM manipulation.

I'm trying to toggle make a div bold by clicking it(by adding an element instead of using classes or css), and remove the bolding with subsequent clicks.(i.e toggling between bold and normal text).

This is what i've come up with so far.

HTML

```
//more html
<div id="f-author">by Edwin A. Abbott</div> <-- the div to be bolded
//more html
```

my jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#f-author').click(function(){

      if($(this).contents().has('b')){
        $('this').find('b').contents().unwrap();
      }else{
        $(this).wrapInner('<b>');
      }
    });
});
```

Nothing is happening in my code when i click on the div and i've been stuck for a couple of hours trying to figure out what exactly is going wrong.My guess is that the problem lies with the if conditional.

I've tried replacing the if conditional with

if($(this).children().has('b'))

but nothing seems to be working.

I would appreciate anyone pointing out my mistake.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without classes or CSS as requested, this adds and removes the `<b>` tag

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#f-author').on('click', function () {
        if ($('b', this).length) {
            $( $('b', this).get(0).childNodes[0] ).unwrap();
        } else {
            $(this).wrapInner('<b></b>');
        }
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/G9VjX/3/)

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong but doesn't $('b',this) select $('#f-author') AND all the <b> elements in the document instead of the <b> element in $('#f-author')? If so,how and why does it work in your example?

Comment: @Kenneth.J - Nope, it's the context selector, so it selects all `<b>` inside `#f-author`, and internally it looks like `$('#f-author').find('b')`

Comment: I understand that .get(0) is to return the first <b> descendent in $('#f-author'). However, what does .childNode[0] do, and what do we need it for?

Comment: jQuery doesn't really work well with textnodes, so I used plain JS to get the textnode, childNodes gets the childnodes of the `<b>` tag, and [0] gets the first one and wraps in jQuery to unwrap it.

Answer (score 2):

You can handle it simply by switch a specific class that add the bold effect using `toggleClass`.

Css class:

```
.bolder{
    font-weight:Bold;
}
```

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#f-author').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('bolder')
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/LdE6g/